# Maximum JavaScript string size in Snowflake Stored Procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake documentation says that VARCHAR columns are limited to 16 MB uncompressed
    https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#data-types-for-text-strings

```
VARCHAR holds unicode characters.  The maximum length is 16 MB (uncompressed). The maximum number of Unicode characters that can be stored in a VARCHAR column depends on whether the characters are singlebyte or multibyte:

Singlebyte
16,777,216

Multibyte
Between 8,388,608 (2 bytes per character) and 4,194,304 (4 bytes per character)

If a length is not specified, the default is the maximum length.
```

Snowflake documentation says that VARCHAR data is automatically converted to JavaScript string data type.
    https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#sql-and-javascript-data-type-mapping

**QUESTION:**
If I call a Snowflake procedure (or JavaScript UDF) and pass in the VARCHAR data from a table, is there a size limitation in the Snowflake Procedure, or will it handle a 16MB string variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript will handle up to 16MB:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MaxParam("STRING" VARCHAR)
RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT STRICT IMMUTABLE AS
'return STRING;';

CREATE TABLE T AS SELECT LPAD('111', 16777216, '0') STR;
SELECT MaxParam(STR) FROM T;
=> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000...

SELECT MaxParam(LPAD('111', 16777217, '0'));
=> String '(padded string)' is too long and would be truncated
(Error message is from LPAD, not JS)
```

Comment: Thanks Hans!  If I knew JavaScript as well as you I could have answered it myself, but this will be good for others to reference.  And thanks for your map function to deal with NULL parameters showing up as Undefined!

Comment: I believe that this has more to do with the 16MB limit of the SQL VARCHAR data type in Snowflake than JavaScript, actually.  Not tested, I'm sure JavaScript can handle text > 16MB inside a procedure/function.  You found some of my old stuff, maybe?  I could never understand why SQL NULL has to be mapped to undefined instead of null in the Stored Procedures API.